# android sound app sdk or ndk?

Tags: android, audio

I've been experimenting with making an android app for the past week or two and have reached a point where I need to decide on a general plan of action concerning the code I'm writing.

**started with SoundPool, easy to use, not very flexible.  went on to AudioTrack, seems good but slow.**

So now I'm looking at the ndk..
Does the ndk have direct access to AudioTrack? or something else?

What is the general concensus on this kind of thing?

A guess is to make the UI in java and the 'sound engine' in C++

I'd like to get started on the right track before I write too much.

**edit:**

It is a music studio that plays and manipulates wav files from the sdcard as well as realtime sound synthesis.

Comment: You might want to give a little more detail about your app, otherwise we can't really give any reasonable suggestions with only knowing that it's an "Android sound app".

Comment: ok edited the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of Audio Latency issues in Android. There's really not anything that can be done about it. It seems like ICS (4.0) may have done some improvements on it, from what I've read.

You could subscribe to Andraudio and you'd actually be better off directing Android Audio questions through their emailing list than through Stackoverflow:
http://music.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/andraudio

Comment: We created a piece that details Android latency problems, using data from a Google Nexus 9. See here: http://superpowered.com/androidaudiopathlatency/

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK doesn’t offer a fully featured audio processing solution like Core Audio on iOS. The available features are exposed through OpenSL ES interface. Any audio processing feature's availability is dependent on the device manufacturer’s Android flavor and configuration, so you can not rely on them.

To wit, the infamous Android fragmentation problem is even bigger in audio.

Even worse, if a device reports an audio feature available, it may still not work properly. For example: audio playback rate on a Samsung Galaxy Note III.

Realtime sound synthesis? None of the Android SDK’s features are designed for that.

The best way is doing the UI in Java and dealing with sound in C++.

There are some 'audio engine' offers on the web, but many of them are just “wrappers” around the same thing.

As cofounder of Superpowered, allow me to recommend the use the Superpowered Audio SDK, which is a total audio processing solution designed for real-time and highest performance, without any dependency on Android’s audio offerings, and runs on all.

http://superpowered.com/

Comment: Your Android "SDK" is really great! But you don't have yet a good docs for Android (all docs are for iOS only) and also you didn't mention that its an NDK project (written on C), so usual SDK dev can't event try it. And its definitely not for AndroidStudio. You provided only one example which is great by itself but has some bugs. It uses some features but its less then a half of iOS examples if compared...

Comment: Hi Stan,

Since http://Superpowered.com is a cross-platform SDK, the API is the same on both platforms. Docs apply to both iOS and Android.

The example project runs great in the official Android development
environment (Android Studio is still beta), and can be imported to
Android Studio as well. As Android Studio doesn't support NDK yet, you need to build the libs from the command-line, but they are pre-built anyway.

What kind of bugs did you encounter in the example project?

Comment: The bug: player does not stop playing when user presses Home button and when user returns to app he can't stop playing by pressing play/pause button. Instead player starts playing one more time so you hear a cacophony. This bug is easy to fix.  
About SDK/API: base developing language in AOS is Java. But to use Java with your SDK I need to develop a JNI first which is not always possible for any Android dev. For instance: I'm an Oracle Java certified developer BUT I don't "speak" neither C nor C++ so I can't use your SDK since there is no ready to use JNI which covers all features of SDK/API.

Comment: Actually I find your lib really super good and its really low latency lib. I'd like to use in my project but the C/NDK/JNI is a problem for me and it's so for most AOS developers aswell. Maybe that's the reason why there are mostly iOS apps based on your lib. I do realize that you did a great job and moreover you provide this lib for free, so C/NDK/JNI barrier is my own problem and I have no right to make you to develop JNI part. I just wanna mention that my problem could be a big issue for you too speaking of popularity of your lib.

Comment: Additionally your sample has only libSuperpoweredARM and libSuperpoweredX86 implementations, however Android has also MIPS and x86_64 and actually there are 2 ARMS: ARMv5TE and ARMv7-A. I was able to modify the build script to compile both ARMs and x86 but I was unable to compile MIPS and x86_64.

Comment: Hi Stan -- just saw this -- wrt MIPS, how many mobile devices run on MIPS right now? Some number close to 0.  :)

Comment: They have even MIPS64 now. However I can say that MIPS devices are really rare.

Comment: "I write Java, not C/C++, so I can't use your lib" is a highly fallible argument. You learned Java. You can learn C/C++. It's an inconvenience, but it doesn't make the lib useless, and learning new languages is always fun, or at least informative.

Comment: can any body show me the way to play simple audio file with superpowered sdk i want just to play pause and loop audio